# Кэширование в обозревателе

Tags: jquery, javascript

Что нужно, что бы обозреватель запомнил изменения?

Код html:

```
<p class="fon">изменить фон</p>
```

Код jquery:

```
$('.fon').click(function() {
$('body').css("background", "yellow");
});
```

При нажатие на надпись "изменить фон", фон меняется, но при обновлении страницы он становится как был раньше. Нужно, что браузер запомнил изменения и не менял их даже при обновлении страницу. Как этого добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сохранить фон где нибудь, можно на сервере в сессии, можно на клиентской стороне в cookie. Думаю вам более интересна клиентская сторона так что прочтите [работа с cookie в jquery](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2008/42.html)